# Make [google-protobuf] a synonym of [protocol-buffers]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I think both tags are synonyms:

- [google-protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-protobuf)
- [protocol-buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protocol-buffers)

Comment: Agree, but the other way around: [protocol-buffers] should be the main tag.

Comment: Yes, ok. I don't care which one wins.

Comment: I thought about it again. I think the same now. `protocol-buffers` should win. Because sooner or later the dominant market share of microsoft will be that big, that no one will remember the company "google" (joke).

Comment: Got my vote, just need [another 3 now](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/protocol-buffers/synonyms)

Comment: @DavidG or just needs someone with a diamond who also happens to know about protobuf... :)

Comment: @MarcGravell You're just showing off now :) (though you could have marked this as status-completed!)